# SMS Retriever API - Generate 11 char hash code for app specific keystore file

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am trying to implement sms retriever api to read OTP code message without having to add read_sms permission.

The help doc [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request), ask user to generate hash code specific to app.

I have generated the code as required but still

`<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>`

broadcast receiver is not firing up.

How can I debug this?

I am testing this by sending a SMS from one mobile to another and I am following the SMS requirement as specified in the document above.

Also, 
There are various methods mentioned to generated hash code. I have tried them all. Problem is each method generated different hash.

I have tried for both debug and release keystore.

Here are those various methods:

1. linux command as describe here - [help doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string)
2. sms_retriever_hash_v9 [file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/bin/sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh) as described [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/tree/master/sms-verification/android)
3. By including [AppSignatureHelper](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) from sample app.

Comment: I am using the signature from AppSignatureHelper still not receiving the OTP, could you please help how you got it working.

Comment: I included AppSignatureHelper in my app. And after you run it, you get the 11 char hash key. Use this hash key in message (for message format and other thing use the help doc.

You can send the message from regular phone. Just ensure that the format is maintained.

Also check that you have included the broadcast receiver with action :

`<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>`

and startSmsRetriever task is started successfully.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I follow all the necessary steps but BroadcastReceiver is not firing and the AppSignatureHelper.java file returns the hash code: BmdW3GtyCCK maybe it is not right. please help.

Comment: @RachitMishra do we need to call that AppSignatureHelper.class anywhere in the app or just included is enough?

Comment: @AjayJayendran You can call that class to get the 11 char hash key which you need to include in your message. So its not mandatory class. Its need just to get the hash key. You can get the key by various other ways as mentioned in the doc.

Comment: I found the key.its working in my laptop but the receiver is not triggering on other machines.do we need to generate by production key store?do you removed that AppSignaturehelper class after generating the key?

Comment: the keys will be different for production and debug. also this class is helpful in generating the key. which can also be done by the provided python file.

Comment: You can remove the class. Also check that you have included the broadcast receiver with action : `<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/> ` . Dev or production does not matter if you are using key generated from AppSignatureHelper class

Comment: @RachitMishra yes you are right, it's working in dev where the hash key was generated from AppSignatureHelper.class. How should I generate a key for production? I have tried with production keystore but it's not working with production's generated hash key.do I need to replace the signature while creating productions' hash key? should we have to use the same signature for both debug and production?

Comment: Look at this page here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#generating_a_one-time_code

Comment: @RachitMishra I did the same thing only.After generating the key with the production keystore , do we need to store the signature or Sha key to play store or any other dashboard.?

Comment: @AjayJayendran You dont need to store the key at playstore or anywhere else. Using the helper class, generate the hash key for debug signed and production release sign key. As the hash key depends on the key used to signing the app. Once you have got the hash key, used it in sms and you can remove the class from app source code as you no longer need it. Also upvote the question if it helps.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha But after uploading the app to the play store, it's not working. Also, we have enabled google app signing, where google play store replaces the old signatures, key and generates a new one.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha i am also trying same thing but broadcast receiver is not firing up,after 5 min its fire with timeout status.kindly help me .

Comment: @rafeek Pl go through the comments... Have you registered the broadcast receiver... There was an error in Android document... Pl verify the action name... Also test with both text message format and with key generated by the Java program

Comment: @SasukeUchiha i follow the step from below https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request   key generate i am using  AppSignaturehelper class.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha any updates?

Answer (score 4):

The first linux command specifies the alias name as `MyAndroidKey` but yours might be different. You can find out your alias name by

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore $KEYSTORE
```

where `$KEYSTORE` is your keystore file.

With the alias name, you can try using the following two commands to verify if the results are the same:

- `keytool -alias MyAndroidKey -exportcert -keystore $KEYSTORE | xxd -p`
- `keytool -list -rfc -keystore $KEYSTORE | sed -e '1,/BEGIN/d' | sed -e '/END/,$d' | tr -d ' \n' | base64 --decode | xxd -p`

Comment: I was using proper alias name and keystore file. No issue there. 
Anyway I found that  hash key generated by AppSignatureHelper works properly. So I am using that method.

Comment: do we need to store that hashcode anywhere in client side? I have generated the hash code from AppSignatureHelper from the client side. and after found my hashcode, I deleted the class file from my app. Is this correct way? I have also tried on using generating hashcode with keytool

Comment: since you need the key hash code to be received to your device through an sms so you can delete the file here and keep the key at your backend.

Comment: Getting 'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Please help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: generated key by using AppSignatureHelper and through command both are same or different?

Comment: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore '~\.android\debug.keystore' | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.opick.app cat | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11` running this command in `java/bin` not asked password.  How generate  release hash using above command ?